# Netsuite saved search formula to multiply two fields

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to use the function(numeric) to multiply quantity sold and vendor purchase price but am having trouble formatting the formula correctly.

I'm trying to use `NVL{quantity}*NVL{item.vendorcostentered}` but it's not working.

It gives an error message and doesn't run the search. I know the field names are correct, I just think I'm using the wrong syntax. I tried using parenthesis instead but it still gives me an unknown error and doesn't run.

Comment: I've used field * 10 before as a numeric formula, are the datatypes correct? Does it give an error message?

Comment: It gives an error message and doesn't run the search. I know the field names are correct, I just think I'm using the wrong syntax. I tried using parenthesis instead but it still gives me an unknown error and doesn't run.

Answer (score 2):

NVL is a formula and takes 2 arguments so your formulanumeric column would need to be:

```
NVL({quantity},0)*NVL({item.vendorcostentered},0)
```